# Solution to the integral equation

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an integral equation of this form :

$\int_{0}^{T} \alpha t_{1} t_{2} \varphi_{k}\left(t_{2}\right) d t_{2}=\lambda_{k} \varphi_{k}\left(t_{1}\right)$

I am trying to solve for $\varphi_{k}(t),  \lambda_{k} $. Is there any proper way of solving this?

I am guessing that the answer is linear in t based on the look of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{T} \alpha t_{1} t_{2} \varphi_{k}\left(t_{2}\right) d t_{2}=\lambda_{k} \varphi_{k}\left(t_{1}\right)$$
Note : If a function $\varphi_{k}\left(t_1\right)$ is solution obviously all functions $C\varphi_{k}\left(t_1\right)$ are solutions with arbitrary constant $C$. The solution is not unique.

$\int_{0}^{T} \alpha t_{1} t_{2} \varphi_{k}\left(t_{2}\right) d t_{2}=\alpha t_{1}\int_{0}^{T}  t_{2} \varphi_{k}\left(t_{2}\right) d t_{2}$
$$\int_{0}^{T} t_{2} \varphi_{k}\left(t_{2}\right) d t_{2}=\frac{\lambda_{k}}{ \alpha t_{1} } \varphi_{k}\left(t_{1}\right)$$
$\int_{0}^{T} t_{2} \varphi_{k}\left(t_{2}\right) d t_{2}$ is a definite integral, thus  constant, say $c_k$.

$\frac{\lambda_{k}}{ \alpha t_{1} } \varphi_{k}\left(t_{1}\right)=c_k$
$$\varphi_{k}\left(t_{1}\right)=\frac{\alpha}{\lambda_k}c_kt_1=C_kt_1$$
We put it into the initial equation :
$$\int_{0}^{T} \alpha t_{1} t_{2} \varphi_{k}\left(t_{2}\right) d t_{2}=\lambda_{k} \varphi_{k}\left(t_{1}\right)=\lambda_k C_k t_1=\int_{0}^{T} \alpha t_{1} t_{2}C_kt_2 d t_{2}$$

$$\lambda_k =\int_{0}^{T} \alpha (t_{2})^2 d t_{2}=\frac{\alpha}{3} T^3 $$
So, $\lambda_k$ is determined. And $ \quad  \varphi_{k}\left(t\right)=C\:t\quad$ with arbitrary coefficient $C$ as expected.

Comment: A minor error: $\lambda_k =\int_{0}^{T} \alpha (t_{2})^2 d t_{2}=\frac{\alpha}{3} T^3, $ right?

Comment: Of course. I fix it straight away.